# how to stop exiting from a script?

Tags: shell, scripting, unix, ksh

I have a script A which call a script G . Inside script G I cannot change any thing (don't have write access).

Inside Script G :

```
ExitProcess ()
{

  case $1 in
    "0" ) echo "$0: Finished successfully."
          exit 0
      ;;
*)  echo "$0: Unknown return status ($1)"
      exit $1
      ;;
 esac

}
```

Due to which I am exiting from Script A , how to stop this ?

Script A:

```
check_status()
{

UserName="sbrk6"
MachineName="sn26"

Tstatus=`ssh -f -T ${UserName}@${MachineName} ps -ef  | grep -w "Manager 1 PR" | egrep -v "grep|less|vi|more"`
Cstatus=`ssh -f -T ${UserName}@${MachineName} ps -ef | grep -w "gt1" | egrep -v "grep|less|vi|more"`

if [ "$Tstatus" ]
then
        if [ "$Cstatus" ]
        then

                Gstatus=`ps -ef  | grep -w "Gth_Hndl" | egrep -v "grep|less|vi|more"`

                if [ -z "$Gstatus" ]
                then
                        genth_start
                fi
        fi
else

        if [ -z "$Tstatus" ]
        then
                if [ -z "$Cstatus" ]
                then

                        Gstatus=`ps -ef  | grep -w "Ghfdjdjd" | egrep -v "grep|less|vi|more"`
                        if [ "$Gstatus" ]
                        then
                                genth_stop
                        fi
                fi
        fi
fi
}


genth_start()
{
echo START

. GD1_Sh 

}


genth_stop()
{
echo STOP

. G_Sh

##This is the Script G ###

}

while :
do
        check_status
done
```

Want this **while** loop to continue until I kill this script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change Script G, then it is probably easiest to arrange to run it as a separate process rather than using the `.` (dot) command to run it in the current process.

If Script G can only be used in the dotted mode, then you could write a third script, call it Script Z, which is designed to run Script G and exit, while your Script A continues happily (reporting the error from Z exiting, then doing whatever is appropriate).

If that is not feasible either, then you could use `eval` and `$(...)` carefully, so that when the functions from Script G that contain exit statements actually exit, they are running in a sub-shell and not in your main shell.  This is fiddlier to do than running Script G separately, whether wrapped with Script Z or not, so I'd use one of those mechanisms first.

Comment: How to run it as a separate process ?

Comment: @Kimi: don't use `. ScriptG`; use `ScriptG` or `sh ScriptG` or some variant.  If you execute it, you won't be able to invoke the functions within ScriptG except by influencing its behaviour with command line arguments (or other environmental mechanisms).  That is why you may end up needing ScriptZ to wrap ScriptG - it can do `. ScriptG` and then invoke the functions that you need invoked.

Comment: @Kimi: Alternatively, after dotting ScriptG, you could arrange to undefine and redefine the ExitProcess function so that it does not exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can [trap exit codes](http://steve-parker.org/sh/trap.shtml) and call a specific function.  In this case you wouldn't want to call exit at the end of the function in Script A.

You can also [return an integer](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions#comment-343091) without using exit.

Example code from [this comment.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions#comment-343091)

```
function return_code_test ()
{
return 50
}
```

Comment: I don't have permissions over the script (G) which is called inside my script (A).

Comment: It is exiting from script G , not returning any thing to script A